# Should I add a comma before 'though' in the following case?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, writing-style

> The dog was lying on his side. **He wasn’t
>   resting though, of that I was sure.** He was dead.

Should I add a comma in the bolded sentence?

> The dog was lying on his side. **He wasn’t
>   resting, though, of that I was sure.** He was dead.

Comment: I am of the school of thought that commas are not necessary until they are necessary to aid comprehension, or to compel deliberation upon the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: when you use *though* to qualify the preceding sentence or clause as "contrary to expectation", *though* is **parenthetical**, and so it needs to be separated from the sentence by commas.

If after *though* you were to continue the sentence, you would need a comma after *though*, too, because parenthesis is marked by stops at both ends.

However, in your sentence, the comma after *though* introduces a **comma splice**, which is generally not recommended. You have two complete sentences with a subject and a finite verb: *he wasn't resting* and *I was sure*. In most cases, you cannot connect two complete sentences with a mere comma: you need a semicolon, a conjunction, a relative pronoun, or a dash (which signifies an anacoluthon, a break of syntax). Using a comma instead results in a comma splice, although there are exceptions, such as enumerations. In this case, you could use a semicolon, or possibly an m-dash (a longer dash).

> The dog was lying on his side. He wasn’t resting, though; of that I was sure. He was dead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker. Why does the *though* introduce a comma splice?

Comment: @janoChen: You have two complete sentences with a subject and a finite verb: *he wasn't resting* and *I was sure*. In most cases, you cannot connect two complete sentence with a mere comma: you need a semicolon, a conjunction, a relative pronoun, or a dash (which signifies an anacoluthon, a break of syntax). *[I have added this to my answer.]*

Comment: Although it's technically a comma splice, I still think this particular sentence is perfectly acceptable. My reasons are these: 1) the component clauses are very short; 2) the second clause directly extends the idea contained in the first clause; and 3) I believe the vast majority of native speakers would have no problem with it. I also think that today, most people  would regard a comma *before* the 'though' as optional. Indeed, its inclusion here strikes me as a rather old-fashioned usage: it suggests a pause where none would exist when the sentence is spoken.